# What happens if a failed server return back from failover?

Tags: mongodb, replication, failover, database

I was going to replication procedure in mongodb, which has the feature of automatic failover.  I tried to make my question in a picture format.

[image]

My question is what happens if the failed server is back online after failover?  This seems like a common practise in database.  This part is totally new to me, so please share your suggestions?

Comment: It's nice to see that there are finally some more people who vote to migrate MongoDB administration questions which have nothing to do with programming. But please vote to migrate them to dba.stackexchange.com, not to serverfault.com.

Comment: The server will just come back as a secondary and use the oplog of the new primary to catch up, if it has writes that don't exist on the rest of the replica set then it will enter a rollback scenario

Comment: @Philipp Since there was very less question in Mongodb I moved to stackoverflow.  Sorry for that, I have voted myself to migrate this question to dba.

Answer (score 4):

Before we jump to the answer, will setup some background:

1. Each server in a replica set maintains oplog. It is log for changes happening on the server. It is a capped collection. Which means that it only maintains recent changes.
2. Primary should have latest oplog. Each secondary syncs itself using oplog of other servers. So it fetches oplog of primary or other secondaries to update itself. It could happen that it lags too much behind, i.e. other secondaries or primary doesn't have intermediate logs. This could happen because of capped nature of oplogs. In such a scenario, secondary does Initial Sync, i.e. full data synch with other servers.

Now coming to your question, what is the state of primary when it comes back. Answer will depend on the state of primary before it fails. Below could be the two cases:

Case 1. Primary, which is about to fail, has the latest changes. Also, at least one of the secondaries has the latest changes. Now Primary fails. The secondary which has the latest changes, will become primary. It will take all changes from mongos or driver. Now what if the earlier primary comes back. It will be a secondary. And will sync itself based on the point 2 mentioned above.

Case 2. Primary, which is about to fail, has the latest changes. And ALL secondaries lag behind primary by couple of changes. Now Primary fails. The newly elected primary will not have the latest changes in this case. But it assumes that it has the latest changes. And it starts behaving as per that. Now if earlier primary comes back, it will be secondary. It  will realise that its oplog is behind as well ahead. Behind because changes happened while it was down. Ahead because it has some changes which are not replicated on other servers. So it will remove the changes which makes its ahead. It will use oplog for this process. This process is called Rollback. But before rolling back, it will log reverted changes in a system rollback file. Now it is not ahead. But behind others. And will sync itself based on the point 2 mentioned above. There is a caveat that administrator will have to manually apply changes from system rollback file. Rollback details can be found at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/

Comment: This is accurate however it lacks doc links to external sources, things like to rollback scenario documentation etc etc

Comment: It also won't put them into a rollback collection but into files on the disk